# Ng-grid filter with 2 condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have requirement to filter table based on

1. single column and
2. across column comparison.

I am using ng-grid to populate table.  It gives feature to filter based on single column.

For across column comparison I am using `grid.refresh()` function. this function calls `grid.registerRowsProcessor( $scope.columnComparionFilter, 200 )`function. I have prepared `columnComparionFilter` function that returns `renderableRows` based on filter. Below is sample code:

```
// function to filter two column based on condition
$scope.columnComparionFilter= function(renderableRows){
    // if filter option selection changed
    if($scope.change){
        if($scope.column1 == undefined)
            return renderableRows;
        if($scope.column2 == undefined)
            return renderableRows;
        if($scope.column1 == $scope.column2){
            console.log('columns for comparision should be different.')
            return renderableRows;
        }
        if($scope.selectedFilter.name == 'compare'){
            renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
                if(row.entity[$scope.column1.field] == row.entity[$scope.column2.field])
                    row.visible = true;
                else
                    row.visible = false;
            });
        }else if($scope.selectedFilter.name == 'distinct'){
            renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
                if(row.entity[$scope.column1.field] != row.entity[$scope.column2.field])
                    row.visible = true;
                else
                    row.visible = false;
            });
        }
    }
    return renderableRows;
};
```

Both filter works fine alone.
But when I tries working both together. It filters based on by default single filter only. It eliminates across column filter.

Can any one help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `grid.registerRowsProcessor()` is core function used by single column filter of `ng-grid`. So when I tried to use same function for across filtering, It lead synchronization problem and single column filter over ruled my customised function.

I have used an alternative for modifying ng-grid data. I have solved it using `notifyDataChange()` function. inside external filter function `columnComparionFilter` I am preparing subset of data based on filter and then I am changing `gridOptions.data` to subset data. See below code:

```
// function to filter two column based on condition
$scope.columnComparionFilter= function(renderableRows){
    // if filter option selection changed
    if($scope.change){
        if($scope.column1 == undefined){
            console.log('Please select first column to compare.')
            return;
        }
        if($scope.column2 == undefined){
            console.log('Please select second column to compare.')
            return;
        }
        if($scope.column1 == $scope.column2){
            console.log('columns for comparision should be different.')
            return;
        }
        if($scope.selectedFilter.name == 'compare'){
            renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {                
                if(row[$scope.column1.field] == row[$scope.column2.field])
                    filterData.push(row)
            });
        }else if($scope.selectedFilter.name == 'distinct'){
            renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
                if(row[$scope.column1.field] != row[$scope.column2.field])
                    filterData.push(row)
            });
        }
        $scope.gridOptions.data = angular.copy(filterData);
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
        return;
    }
};
```